# CallKit Error : Rejecting Incoming Video call when app is in backgorund

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, voip, callkit

We are developing a `VOIP` application with supporting both video and voice calls.

There is an interesting problem for `iOS 10 CallKit` feature. 
If the user rejects the incoming video call by pressing the decline button in less then 4 or 5 seconds (more then 10 seconds it always work) on the native incoming call screen while the application is in the background, the call fails and native call fail UI shows for `iPhone 7` (iphone 6 dont have a problem). This native call error screen has also a problem, see https://openradar.appspot.com/27678801) But same case for incoming voice call works as it has to be.

We also tested the `Whatsapp and Messenger` behavior and realized that the native incoming call screen is not shown when the app is in `backgorund`, they show only a `local notification` for video calls for `iOS 10`.

There must be a problem with the `reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID` API but we could not see any reported bug in web (openradar, etc..). 
Is there anyone who has faced the same problem?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I reported the bug to Apple (id= 29574266), if they returns I will update here too.

Comment: "We also tested the Whatsapp and Messenger behavior and realized that the native incoming call screen is not shown when the app is in backgorund, they show only a local notification for video calls for iOS 10. " That would only be true if you haven't granted microphone/camera permissions. After those permissions have been granted, Whatsapp should show the CallKit screen.

Comment: You are wrong, please check whatsapp behaviour carefully.